# Laravel validating distinct values in array but ignoring keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate a simple array with automatic numeric keys e.g.

```
[0] => 5,
[1] => 9,
[2] => 9
```

Using the following validation rule:

```
'content_types.*' => 'numeric|distinct',
```

But it's not catching the duplicate values and throwing an error when saving `$template->contentTypes()->attach($request->content_type_ids)`. Is the `distinct` rule ignoring the rule as it's not distinct as the key is different and if so how would I validate this? It seems so simple so am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that experiences this..... Make sure your input name is the same as the name you're checking against ‍♂️#schoolboy